# Declare additional Unicode characters in verbatim environments in a Pandoc-generated file

Tags: verbatim, unicode, pandoc

I generate a PDF document via LaTeX with Pandoc. I want to use some additional characters in verbatim environments that are not available by default. Here's a sample input:

```
Math: $\downarrow$

Verbatim:

    stuff
      ↓
    thing

Text: ↓
```

Result of `pandoc -s -o mnwe.tex mnwe.md`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \fi
\fi
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex,
              colorlinks=true,
              linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true,
              colorlinks=true,
              linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

PDFLaTeX compilation log:

```
\begin{document}

Math: $\downarrow$

Verbatim:

\begin{verbatim}
stuff
  ↓
thing
\end{verbatim}
Text: ↓

\end{document}

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./mnwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, farsi, arabic, croatian, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, czech, slov
ak, danish, dutch, finnish, french, basque, ngerman, german, german-x-2009-06-1
9, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ibycus, monogreek, greek, ancientgreek, hungarian, san
skrit, italian, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian2a, mongolian, bokmal, nyn
orsk, romanian, irish, coptic, serbian, turkish, welsh, esperanto, uppersorbian
, estonian, indonesian, interlingua, icelandic, kurmanji, slovenian, polish, po
rtuguese, spanish, galician, catalan, swedish, ukenglish, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/hycolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/xcolor-patch.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ltxmisc/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/bigintcalc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty))
*hyperref using default driver hpdftex*
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def) (./mnwe.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/refcount.sty)) (./mnwe.out)
(./mnwe.out) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:↓ not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.43 \end{verbatim}

? s
OK, entering \scrollmode...

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:↓ not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.44 Text: ↓

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mnwe.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/share/texmf-texlive/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/p
ublic/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on mnwe.pdf (1 page, 32085 bytes).
Transcript written on mnwe.log.
```

I'm using quick-and-dirty ASCII art diagrams, or rather Unicode art, in this document and I want them to stay that way, so using “proper” diagram packages is not an option. I can't change the way Pandoc generates a `verbatim` environment.

I don't mind if the output is ugly, a box containing a `$\downarrow$` would do fine as long as the box has the proper size of the `tt` font. But it has to be entered as the literal character `↓` in the source code. This doesn't have to work in normal text, it's ok if the character can only be used verbatim environments.

I can tell Pandoc to include extra arbitrary LaTeX commands in the header. What can I add to define the character `↓` (U+2193) to print as something resembling `↓` in the right size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the down arrow the answer is `\usepackage{textcomp}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
  \fi
\fi
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              colorlinks=true,
              linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true,
              colorlinks=true,
              linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\begin{document}

Math: $\downarrow$

Verbatim:

\begin{verbatim}
stuff
  ↓
thing
\end{verbatim}
Text: ↓

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So `pandoc -H moredefs.tex -o mnwe.pdf -t latex mnwe.md` with `moredefs.tex` containing `\usepackage{textcomp}`. Nice and easy, thank you.

Comment: How did you find which package to include? I'm running into the same problem with diagonal arrows like "↖" :/

Comment: @Clément I'd say to add to `moredefs.tex` the lines `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and `\newunicodechar{↖}{\ensuremath{\nwarrow}}`

Comment: @Clément I just knew that `textcomp` defines a down arrow and that there is `ts1enc.dfu` providing UTF-8 correspondences with the glyphs in the TS1 encoding (the one accessed to with `textcomp`).

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the newunicodechar solution; the problem with that is that it breaks alignment in verbatim listings :/ (\nwarrow is wider than other arrows)

Comment: @Clément `\resizebox{.5em}{!}{$\nwarrow$}` instead of `\ensuremath{\nwarrow}` (requires `graphicx`).

Comment: @egreg Thanks! For the record (and for others), using xetex or luatex also works perfectly in this setting! (Although it requires another font, since Latin Modern Mono doesn't have the north-west arrow)